# 3D Ribbon plot for a single column

Tags: r, plot, 3d, ribbon

I am able to create the ribbon3D plot for a matrix which has dimensions greater than 1 for rows and columns. I am stuck with a problem when one of the dimensions is 1. meaning if I have 12 rows and a single column then my code gives an error. 
Need help in solving this situation.

The sample data of a table is given as follows:

```
    structure(c(3, 4, 2, 2, 9, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11), .Dim = c(1L, 
11L), .Dimnames = list("Fruits and nuts (excluding oil nuts), fresh or dried", 
    c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
    "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")))
```

The code used for plots is as follows:

```
library(plot3D)

ribbon3D(x = 1:nrow(rs12), y = 1:ncol(rs12), z = rs12, scale = T, expand = .2, bty = "b", along = "y",  
         colvar = rs12, colkey = F, border = "black", shade = 0.1, 
         theta = -50, phi = 40, space = .5, d = 2, 
         curtain = T, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "", main = "Pakistan's Exports to Russia", 
         cex.axis = 0.000000000001, box = F)
```

For those who are interested in how it works for matrix greater than 1. Here is the sample data. But change the matrix name from `rs12` to `tf12` in the code.
The error by running the above code on the above sample is like this, `Error in persp.default(plist$xlim, plist$ylim, z = matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2,  : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected`.

```
dput(tf12)
structure(c(18, 36, 18, 39, 41, 18, 18, 18, 18, 36, 37, 18, 38, 
18, 18, 18, 40, 18, 18, 17, 36, 17, 39, 41, 17, 17, 17, 34, 38, 
36, 17, 34, 17, 17, 17, 40, 17, 17, 16, 38, 34, 40, 41, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 36, 36, 16, 34, 34, 34, 16, 39, 16, 16, 32, 40, 32, 40, 
41, 32, 32, 32, 14, 36, 36, 14, 14, 32, 32, 14, 38, 14, 14, 16, 
38, 33, 39, 41, 33, 16, 33, 33, 37, 36, 16, 33, 16, 16, 16, 40, 
16, 16, 14, 39, 31, 40, 41, 31, 31, 31, 31, 37, 36, 31, 14, 31, 
14, 31, 38, 14, 31, 30, 37, 30, 39, 41, 36, 13, 30, 30, 38, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 13, 13, 15, 38, 32, 39, 41, 32, 15, 15, 
32, 38, 32, 32, 15, 32, 36, 15, 40, 15, 15, 15, 38, 32, 39, 41, 
36, 15, 15, 32, 38, 32, 32, 15, 15, 32, 15, 40, 32, 15, 15, 38, 
32, 39, 41, 36, 15, 15, 32, 32, 32, 36, 15, 32, 36, 15, 40, 15, 
15, 16, 38, 34, 39, 41, 37, 16, 16, 34, 16, 34, 16, 16, 34, 34, 
16, 40, 16, 16), .Dim = c(19L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("Pig iron & spiegeleisen, sponge iron, powder & granu", 
"Ores and concentrates of base metals, n.e.s.", "Waste, parings and scrap, of plastics", 
"Leather", "Textile yarn", "Stone, sand and gravel", "Fish, dried, salted or in brine; smoked fish", 
"Copper", "Non-ferrous base metal waste and scrap, n.e.s.", "Cotton", 
"Fish, fresh (live or dead), chilled or frozen", "Feeding stuff for animals (no unmilled cereals)", 
"Carboxylic acids, anhydrides, halides, per.; derivati.", "Crustaceans, mollusks and aquatic invertebrates", 
"Crude vegetable materials, n.e.s.", "Polymers of ethylene, in primary forms", 
"Cotton fabrics, woven", "Other crude minerals", "Ships, boats & floating structures"
), c("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `ribbon3D`:  it subsets a matrix, but doesn't tell R to keep it as a matrix, so it becomes a vector, and things go badly after that.

You can fix that bug yourself using the `fix()` function to edit it and create a local copy, but you'll just end up with a different error, likely caused by the same issue elsewhere.

I'd suggest you have two choices:

1. Spend some time tracking down and fixing all of these problems.  It's a good chance to learn debugging in R, but will take a while.  Once you have them all fixed, send the list of necessary changes to the maintainer of the `plot3D` package.
2. Write to the maintainer, including your reproducible example, and hope that she has interest and time to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks! since I am not an IT guy so I will prefer to go by the second choice, meanwhile I found another issue that relates to vector and matrix thing you mentioned. I had to refurbish the first sample data. And, hope if that helps someone to go through the excercise.